# how to catch automatically downloading file with python

Tags: python, http

What I want to accomplish is to download an .xlsx file from a link like the below:
https://......./something.do?parameter=[parameter_value]

**Please note that it's meaningless to show the exact link since it's an internal link.**

The problem is that the download starts automatically if I open the link in a browser. But when I want to do it programmatically, I cannot get the exact link of the file.

I figured out that in http response header the content-disposition attribute contains the file name like this:
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ABCD.xlsx"

But I couldn't catch the file so far, only the html code of the site.

Currently my python code looks like this:

```
import requests
urlBase = 'link to the authetication page'
urlFile = 'https://......./something.do?parameter=[parameter_value]' //like the above link
user = 'username'
pw = 'password'

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = (user, pw)

auth = session.post(urlBase)
response = session.get(urlFile)
```

Response is currently showing the html code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's more to downloading a file than just reading the response object.  You'll have to open a file on your machine and then write the data from the socket into the file.  See the [`requests` docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content)

Comment: use `chrome developer tools` to see what your browser is really requesting and what is the response from the http server (your can see both request and response exact headers); if you can't get the same, you may be under redirection, or your are no using the required cookies, or whatever: get the actual request and response headers of your browser when the file is correctly downloaded